# Verifying launch of 3rd party application using Xamarin UITest (blackbox)

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, read-eval-print-loop, uitest

I am creating automation to validate our UI.
There is a button that launches a "Help" webpage when pressed.
This is an independent launch (i.e. just sent to the devices default web browser).

How do I determine:
1.  What is the current foreground application on the device?
2.  Dismissing that current foreground application (or just returning to my app).  Is there a .Query() that is available?
3.  Can I validate the function of code to do the above 2 items using REPL?

I am using Xamarin UITest.  Both Android and iOS.

Comment: That is not possible via UITest... well on Android you could write a bunch of platform-based code to determine the foregrounded app, create an Android Service to run that code in the app being tested, etc... and then access it via a Calabash backdoor call. iOS will just not allow you to do that... Other test frameworks like Appium would allow you to do that.

Comment: To add to @SushiHangover's correct answer, I'll note that if you did create a workaround for working with another app; it would only work for local testing, and not in App Center.